# Single and multiple method naming C#

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, naming

I have a question about method naming. I have two methods:

```
private UserReport CreateUserReport(string userId, Report report)

private IEnumerable<UserReport> CreateUserReports(string userId, IEnumerable<Report> reports)
```

Should I add 's' to second method name or use `CreateUserReport` name for two methods, i.e. they will differ only in signature?

Comment: It is enough that they are different in signiture, they can have same name as long as number or types of arguments are different.

Comment: If the former creates one and the latter products multiple it would make sense for `s` to be at the end of the latter (due to how English works). The compiler doesn't _require_ it though.

Comment: Sure, why not. IMO, the only actual argument in naming-convention debate is that: Make sure that you follow a standard in all your code. If it a unconventional style, document it too.

Comment: I know this, but here I would like to hear advice on clean code. How will the programmer who reads my code be clearer, will he look at the signature in order to determine what he is doing? How is it better?

Comment: One nice thing about programming in C# is that you can do *anything*, well, almost anything....

Comment: The only rule you ned to consider here is that a method name should match the purpose of the method. If the purpose of the method is to create a single report then the method name should reflect that. How does `CreateUserReport` indicate returning a list containing multiple reports? It doesn't, so it's obviously an inappropriate name.

Comment: `How is it better?` Because most programmers will understand that `CreateApple` will make one apple and `CreateApples` will make multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not only differ in signature but in their purpose as well. The one above generates single report while the one below generates multiple of them. I would strongly suggest that because of that you should use different names for them. For methods with the same name I think it would be advisable that return type should match and they only differ in parameters.